# SQL Server Express - Can't find data I created

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I created a database called psview within a brand new docker SQL Server Express container. I selected the database that has no tables yet and ran this query against a JSON file that I already copied to the container's C: drive.

```
SELECT value
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\data.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
```

I can see it created tons of rows from the data.json but I have no idea where it put the data because I don't see that it created any tables and I looked everywhere even in the pre-configured databases like the System Databases.

Where can I find my data?

Comment: Can you post the log u saw that confirms the rows creation?

Comment: @yonBav I've since been screwing around like running "select * from dbo.psview" which it says it can't find by the way, so the messages window no longer contains the info.  But it showed each of the rows in the db over and over again, ran for a while (it's a 90mb json file) then said that it successfully completed.

Comment: A `select` isn't going to put the data anywhere.

Comment: As @shawnt00 said, your example query isn't `INSERT`ing the data into a table so it isn't persisted anywhere. The `SELECT` is just streaming the results into whatever client tool you're using.

Comment: @shawnt00 yes ofcourse but i think he only posted the way he selected the value from the json file. Any way here is a great guide. I checked and it works great. https://www.pauric.blog/How-To-Import-JSON-To-SQL-Server/#5-save-the-rowsets-into-a-table

Comment: @Helzgate anyway if you didn't save the select result and used it in an insert or a select into statement. That's of course the problem as shawnt00 said.